# How can I get button value in textbox of model pop up?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, popup

I have dynamic buttons

[image]

when I click on button a popup should appear with a textbox.

My button code is

```
echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value='.$row['country_id'].' id="update" >Update</button>';
```

My jQuery code is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#update").click(function(){ 
      var butval = $("#update").val();
      $("#ctext").val(butval);
  });
});
```

Modal popup is

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" id="ctext" value="<?php  ;?>">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="update">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and your question is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@suchit Thanks for your help. 
this code is working

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn"  data-toggle="modal"       value='.$row['country_name'].' id='.$row['country_name'].' >Update</button>;


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".btn").click(function(){ 
          var butval = this.id;
          $("#ctext").val(butval);
          $("#myModal").modal('show');
      });
    });
 } );
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For this kind of case , You must use data attribute of HTML5.**

```
echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-btn="'..$row['country_id']..'" value='.$row['country_id'].' id="update" >Update</button>';
```

And in the Modal popup,

Here is the magic script that will solve your problem.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#update").click(function(){ 
      // this is the value you get which is in data attribute of update button.
      var btn_value= $(this).data('btn');
      $('#myModal')
      .find('#ctext').val(btn_value).end()                            
      .modal('show'); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for multiple buttons using class:** You can try the below. first remove `data-target="#myModal"` from button then get the value and write it to input then open the modal:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".update").click(function(){ 
           var butval = $(this).val();     
           $("#ctext").val(butval);
           $("#myModal").modal('show');
       });
     });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success update"   value='2'  >Update</button> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success update"   value='3'  >Update</button> 
  <!-- see the button attributes changes  -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" id="ctext" >
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="update">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: only first button is working.well I am generating these button through while loop.

Comment: @kapildevsharma then for each button you have to give different id. i'll suggest use class instead. try the update using class

Comment: @kapildevsharma what is not working. I can see the sample code is working file and showing different values on both the buttons.Please be specific.

Comment: button class="btn"   and script code is $( function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".btn").click(function(){ 
           var butval = $(".btn").val();
           $("#ctext").val(butval);
           $("#myModal").modal('show');
       });
     });
  } );

Comment: The solution is <script>
$( function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".btn").click(function(){ 
           var butval = this.id;
           $("#ctext").val(butval);
           $("#myModal").modal('show');
       });
     });
  } );
</script>

Comment: @kapildevsharma  `$( function()`  and  `$(document).ready(function(){` are same the first one is  the `short hand` for `second`. and in my answer i have used class update. if the answer is then same then you should accept the answer not post another `until unless` they are different.